# How to mix colors to reach a target color

Tags: python, colors

I have a list of initial colors that can be mixed at different ratios to reach a target color, represented in RGB values. To limit the options, I can only use 3 initial colors in each mix to get as close as possible to the target color. How should I approach searching for those combinations efficiently?

I'm currently mixing colors by calculating a weighted average of the RGB values. If possible, I would like to switch to a more realistic mixing method like [this](https://github.com/scrtwpns/mixbox) after implementing the basic one

Comment: Is this solved? If you have a Red, a Green and a Blue in your initial colors... then there's no problem to create any other color. You can mix colors by adding the r-g-b parts of **A** to their related part in **B** ( `r1 + r2` etc. If result is higher than 255, then result is trimmed to be a 255). Mixing Red `FF0000` + Green `00FF00` gets you Yellow `FFFF00`. Is that what you want?